# How to get the id value of a button using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table which gets data from my database. My table has the columns id,name,url and so forth. Under my ID column I have my settings drop down buttons in each row which I created dynamically using this code:

```
html.Append("<li><button ID='btnDelete' value='"
    + row[column.ColumnName]
    + "' OnClick='btnDelete_Click' runat='server'>Delete</button></li>");
```

(This is the delete button in the drop down list)

When inspecting the code while debugging, I can see the ID of each row when I select the delete button. I see it in the `"value = "`. I want to use that value.
Please advice how I can get it on my code.

Debugging my code while inspecting it:

[image]

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? Why you concatenate strings to build the HTML? You should use controls

Comment: Yes it is. I used HTML because that's how my boss wants it.

Comment: Then ask your boss why you use ASP.NET at all. How you render the html, `Response.Write(html)`?

Comment: Also, where in your code you try to get this Id? This button doesn't exist at server because you haven't added it as control to the page's control-collection. So you also can't handle it's click event there. You could use a hack, like using javascript to store the value in a hiddenfield and then read that at server-side.

Comment: Maybe you should use JS: `document.getElementById('btnDelete')`, but... if the control is inside a loop, you need to assign different IDs for them (also avoid creating HTML with `runat="server"` attribute from code behind, use HTML literal control class instead).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the sender parameter to get button value:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)        
{
        var senderButton = sender as HtmlButton;
        DeleteById(senderButton.Attributes["Value"]);
}
```

Untested Code :(